# Finding sum of geometric sequence with modulo 10^9+7 with my program

Tags: algorithm, math, pascal

The problem is given as:
Output the answer of (A^1+A^2+A^3+...+A^K) modulo 1,000,000,007, where 1≤ A, K ≤ 10^9, and A and K must be an integer.

I am trying to write a program to compute the above question. I have tried using the formula for geometric sequence, then applying the modulo on the answer. Since the results must be an integer as well, finding modulo inverse is not required.

Below is the code I have now, its in pascal

```pascal
Var
a,k,i:longint;
power,sum: int64;
Begin
    Readln(a,k);
    power := 1;
    For i := 1 to k do
    power := ((power mod 1000000007) * a) mod 1000000007;
    sum := a * (power-1) div (a-1);
    Writeln(sum mod 1000000007);
End.
```

This task came from my school, they do not give away their test data to the students. Hence I do not know why or where my program is wrong. I only know that my program outputs the wrong answer for their test data.

Comment: Do you have a programming question? If so, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes it's a programming question

Comment: Ok, then please explain in the question what you've tried and what isn't working, and what the symptoms of this problem are (error messages, wrong output, etc). Provide a complete example that illustrates the problem. In the most common solution to this problem, a modular inverse is indeed required.

Comment: You more or less just stated the problem and said that you are trying to do it yourself. I guess your question is "how to do it"? In that case, note that SO is not a code writing service. We can help with specific questions, as in, you are trying yourself and are stuck at a specific step in your program logic. In any case, you have to post your code and explain your approach. Show us that you tried it. (see [ask] and [help])

Comment: You can use the fact that x^1 + ... + x^(2n) = (1+x^n)(x^1 + ... + x^n) to form a recurrence. Then use [fast exponentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I will include everything next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without calculating a modular inverse, you can calculate it recursively using:

1+ A + A<sup>2</sup> + A<sup>3</sup> + ... + A<sup>k</sup>

= 1 + (A + A<sup>2</sup>)(1 + A<sup>2</sup> + (A<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + ... + (A<sup>2</sup>)<sup>k/2-1</sup>)

That's for even k.  For odd k:

1+ A + A<sup>2</sup> + A<sup>3</sup> + ... + A<sup>k</sup>

= (1 + A)(1 + A<sup>2</sup> + (A<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + ... + (A<sup>2</sup>)<sup>(k-1)/2</sup>)

Since k is divided by 2 in each recursive call, the resulting algorithm has O(log k) complexity.  In java:

```
static int modSumAtoAk(int A, int k, int mod)
{
    return (modSum1ToAk(A, k, mod) + mod-1) % mod;
}

static int modSum1ToAk(int A, int k, int mod)
{
    long sum;
    if (k < 5) {
        //k is small -- just iterate
        sum = 0;
        long x = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<=k; ++i) {
            sum = (sum+x) % mod;
            x = (x*A) % mod;
        }
        return (int)sum;
    }
    //k is big
    int A2 = (int)( ((long)A)*A % mod );
    if ((k%2)==0) {
        // k even
        sum = modSum1ToAk(A2, (k/2)-1, mod);
        sum = (sum + sum*A) % mod;
        sum = ((sum * A) + 1) % mod;
    } else {
        // k odd
        sum = modSum1ToAk(A2, (k-1)/2, mod);
        sum = (sum + sum*A) % mod;
    }
    return (int)sum;
}
```

Note that I've been very careful to make sure that each product is done in 64 bits, and to reduce by the modulus after each one.

With a little math, the above can be converted to an iterative version that doesn't require any storage:

```
static int modSumAtoAk(int A, int k, int mod)
{
    // first, we calculate the sum of all 1... A^k
    // we'll refer to that as SUM1 in comments below

    long fac=1;
    long add=0;

    //INVARIANT: SUM1 = add + fac*(sum 1...A^k)
    //this will remain true as we change k

    while (k > 0) {
        //above INVARIANT is true here, too

        long newmul, newadd;
        if ((k%2)==0) {
            //k is even.  sum 1...A^k = 1+A*(sum 1...A^(k-1))
            newmul = A;
            newadd = 1;
            k-=1;
        } else {
            //k is odd.
            newmul = A+1L;
            newadd = 0;
            A = (int)(((long)A) * A % mod);
            k = (k-1)/2;
        }
        //SUM1 = add + fac * (newadd + newmul*(sum 1...Ak))
        //     = add+fac*newadd + fac*newmul*(sum 1...Ak)

        add = (add+fac*newadd) % mod;
        fac = (fac*newmul) % mod;

        //INVARIANT is restored
    }

    // k == 0
    long sum1 = fac + add;
    return (int)((sum1 + mod -1) % mod);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why is 'mod' added to 'sum1' again at the final result?

Comment: @SuperPannda it's `mod - 1`.  The stuff above computes the sum 1 + A + ... + A^k.  The answer you want doesn't have that `1` in it, so I subtract it at the end.  The `%` operator in java (and most other languages) does strange things with negative numbers, so instead of just subtracting `1`, I add `mod - 1` so that the argument to the '%' operator is always positive.